# Find the minimum, irreducible polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

I have to find the minimum, irreducible polynomial of $$e^{\pi i/3}$$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I have done the following:

$e^{\pi i/3}$ is a root of the equation $x^6-1=0$, right??

$$x^6-1=(x-1)(x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)$$

How could I continue??

Comment: Note that minimal polynomials over a field are necessarily irreducible.

Comment: @hardmath From Euler's identity, we have that $$e^{i \pi}+1=0$$ so is $\displaystyle{e^{(\pi i/3)}}$ a root of $$x^3+1=0$$ ??

Comment: So far, so good, but there is a factor $x+1$ to remove.

Comment: It is $$x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$ right?? Since $x+1=0$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Q}$, and $x^2-x+1=0$ has not, the minimal polynomial is $$x^2-x+1$$ right??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that it is a root of $(x^3+1) = (x+1)(x^2-x+1)$

So its minimal polynomial is $x^2-x+1$.

Comment: Isn't it $$e^{i \pi}+1=0$$ ?? So, shouldn't $\displaystyle{e^{\pi i/3}}$ be a root of $x^3+1$ ??

Comment: You are right, @MaryStar; can you think of a way to factorize $x^3+1$ similar to what Crostul wrote? Namely, what remains when $x^3+1$ is divided by $x+1$?

Comment: It is $$x^3+1=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)$$ right?? Since $x+1=0$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Q}$, and $x^2-x+1=0$ has not, the minimal polynomial is $$x^2-x+1$$ right??

Comment: Sorry, I will edit.